# Support multiple themes under single build in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have to change the theme based on some event. What i understood from sencha docs and kitchen sink is we have to make entries of all the themes under "builds" block of app.json

```
"builds": {
     "classic": {
        "toolkit": "classic",
        "theme": "theme-classic"
    },
    "triton": {
        "toolkit": "classic",
        "theme": "theme-triton"
    }
},
```

Post build, we can reload application as below to get specific theme.

```
location.search = "/?profile=classic";
location.search = "/?profile=triton";
```

But its not working as expected. Any hints please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only halfway there. Sencha Cmd will generate different manifests for your themes. Now you now have to chose the corresponding manifest upon application load. Take a look at [Dynamic Manifest](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.5.0/guides/microloader.html#microloader_-_dynamic_manifest) section from Microloader's docs.

> There are times when you may want to select a build profile
>   client-side. To simplify this, the Microloader defines a hook method
>   called “Ext.beforeLoad”. If you define this method like the following,
>   you can control the name or content of “Ext.manifest” prior to the
>   Microloader processing it while leveraging its platform detection.

For your case it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Ext = Ext || {};
    Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
        var theme = location.href.match(/profile=([\w-]+)/);
        theme  = (theme && theme[1]) || 'classic';
        Ext.manifest = theme;
    };
</script>
```